# I am trying to output a table in my pdf from R, but it is not showing up

Tags: r, dataframe, pdf, output

I have created a dataframe of results that I would like to output as a table into my pdf when I knit my rmarkdown. However, the table is showing up when I run the code chunk, but not in my actual pdf when I knit.

```
---
title: "Analysis 2"
author: "(abalamur)"
date: "May 12, 2021"
output: pdf_document
linestretch: 1.241
fontsize: 12pt
fontfamily: mathpazo
---
```

```
{r, results = "hide"}

sd(errors[,1])/sqrt(length(errors[,1]))
sd(errors[,2])/sqrt(length(errors[,2]))
#grid.table(apply(errors, 2, mean))

df = data.frame("Model" = c("Unlagged", "Lagged"), "Pred Error" = c(199.057, 184.7143), "Std Error" = c(21.44976, 19.12065))

knitr::kable(df)
```

I put results="hide" because I do not want the code to show up in my final pdf.

Comment: Sure, I just posted it!

Comment: You need LaTex installed to knit PDF output. You have that? Let us know what operating system you're using from the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: my operating system is macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: You can download MacTeX from here: https://tug.org/mactex/ Hopefully you have an Intel processor or this will be more complicted.